Azure Tagging Policy Customize Error information
I am trying to customize or get more details from Policy Tagging Error during resource creation.
When creating Resource Group this is the info i get witch would be suficiant.

But when creating resource all i get is this.

I am using RSG https://www.azadvertizer.net/azpolicyadvertizer/96670d01-0a4d-4649-9c89-2d3abc0a5025.html
and for RS I am using https://www.azadvertizer.net/azpolicyadvertizer/96670d01-0a4d-4649-9c89-2d3abc0a5025.html
Dose any one know if this is just a limitation of the Azure policy.  Any input would be appreciated thatnks.
I have been searching on google and reviwing the policies and my configuration.
